# How do I built the ros-indigo-pointgrey-camera-driver aptitude package for the Ubuntu trusty armhf platform?

Tags: ros, pointgrey, armhf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's pretty simple. It seems that only ros-jade-pointgrey-camera-driver aptitude package is available for armhf. I'd rather continue to use indigo if possible, and I know that ros-indigo-pointgrey-camera-driver is available on other platforms.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209171/how-do-i-built-the-ros-indigo-pointgrey-camera-driver-aptitude-package-for-the-ubuntu-trusty-armhf-platform?/) by [Bryce](https://answers.ros.org/users/22422/bryce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-05-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-05-13**:
Why do you want to build the apt package? Why not just install the package from source?

**Comment by [Bryce](https://answers.ros.org/users/22422/bryce/) on 2015-05-13**:
I have actually tried that, and I get errors when I run the camera.launch file:

Could not find library corresponding to plugin pointgrey_camera_driver/PointGreyCameraNodelet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I was building Indigo packages for armhf six months ago, the pointgrey driver included a binary driver that only supported x86, so it didn't build on ARM.

It looks like this has been resolved in a recent release ( https://github.com/ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver/issues/32 ), but the fix hasn't made it back to the Indigo builds for armhf yet.

You should be able to check out the latest version from source, build and run it on armhf. Perhaps you just forgot to build it before you tried to run it?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bryce](https://answers.ros.org/users/22422/bryce/) on 2015-05-14**:
Thanks, turns out I'm not used to the new catkin_make system. There's some setup.bash script that catkin_make generates that I needed to source in order for all the paths to line up. That said, I'm not too sure this package is working well on armhf, but that's another conversation.